# Перестала запускаться IDE Intellij 2022.1

Tags: intellij-idea

Работал в Intellij. Пытался настроить правильную кодировку, чтобы русский язык в консоли отображался. Настроил. Но после перезапуска выдает ошибку.

[image: Сообщение об ошибке при запуске программы Intellij]

Переустановка не помогла. Где еще искать причину?

Проблема с кодировкой не решена.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В переменной JAVA_OPTIONS или как там она называется?

Comment: Спасибо. Может подскажете как кодировку правильно настроить. Русский в консоли, то выводит то не выводит.